# OpenCV using Fourier Transform to get frequency spectrogram

Tags: opencv, fft, frequency, dft, audio-processing

I have captured a input sound signal with my microphone and visualized it in a OpenCV Mat:

[image: Mat of the input sound]

I read each 20 samples (=each 20 pixels in x-direction of the "sound-mat") and multiply it with the hann-window-function.
Then, I perform the dft (decrete fourier transform) in OpenCV ([docs here](http://www.docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft)) of this windowed sequence.
Here is an example of the mangitude output of the dft of such a 20-sample signal:

[image: dft output of a 20-sample-sequence]

But how can I get a frequency spectrogram? Is the described attempt right? What do I have to do with these dft outputs to get a spectrogram?

Sorry for not posting the pictures; only links. As I am new to stackoverflow, I cannot post pictures directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work with such an image.
You have to use a 1D vector (1D Mat in OpenCV doesn't exist) that has as size the length of your audio signal.

Than you have to do the dft/fft on a windowed (e.g. hann-window) section of the sound. Do this for every section, so that you get the frequency of each such a section. The output can be put together to a spectrogram.

Answer (score 0):

20 samples usually is too short piece to obtain reasonable frequency range and resolution (it depends on sample frequency like 44100 Hz).

When you make FT and calculate magnitude for some time range starting at `t`, build vertical line segment at X-coordinate t. Y-coordinate on this segment is frequency - usually logarithmic scale is used. Pixel intensity is sum of magnitude values in some range around frequency f (you may use also color coding of intensity).

l-th entry of magnitude array corresponds to frequency

```
f=2*Pi*F/N
```

where F - discretization (sample) frequency (like 44100 Hz), N  - size of Fourier transform (like 1024)

Pseudocode
`PixelValue[x = a * t, y = b * log2(i)] =  c * Sum(l=i/2..i) FTAmplitude[l]`

a,b,c are scale coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not understand where the frequencies and its intensity is in the magnitude image. First, is the approach right to transform an audio signal into such an image (first image in question) and to do the FT on a region of interest that has the sound-image's Y-size and the number of samples that I want do analyse as X-size?
For me, the magnitude image should represent somewhere the intensity of each frequency in the analyzed audio sequence.

Comment: spectrogram: http://sail.usc.edu/Peter/mystery/mystery.jpg  The first image - graph of audio signal. FT should be carried out on audio data array, not on picture. Information about frequencies added to the post.